# Select an a tag inside a div and make a popup using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm stuck in trying to make a popup using jQuery for a second A tag inside a div. You can see what I tried here:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".sites").find("a").eq(1).css("color", "red").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    show: {
      effect: "fade",
      duration: 500
    },
    hide: {
      effect: "fade",
      duration: 500
    }
  });

  $(".sites").find("a").eq(1).on("click", function() {
    $(".sites").find("a").eq(1).dialog("open");
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  margin: 2rem 0 0 2rem;
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

a {
  display: block;
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: blue;
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<p>
  Finding the second a tag, colouring it in red, then display a pop-up on click when clicking Site 2
</p>


<div class="sites">
  <a href="https://www.site1.com">Site 1</a>
  <br>
  <a href="https://www.site2.com">Site 2</a>
</div>
```

How do I force the dialogue popup to open and display "Hello !"?

Comment: @freedomn-m I was using jQuery UI, but if there's a simpler solution, please feel free to let me know about it

Comment: What I want in fact is to display a pop-up when I'm clicking on Site 2. At first, I was thinking to use jQuery UI dialog. Is there a different solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Ids to reference the second element, also, the function call is slightly wrong. Here it's a correct version:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#site2").addClass("color-red");

  $("#site2").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    show: {
      effect: "fade",
      duration: 500
    },
    hide: {
      effect: "fade",
      duration: 500
    }
  }).dialog( "open" );
  });
}());
```

```css
div {
  margin: 2rem 0 0 2rem;
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

a {
  display: block;
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: blue;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.color-red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<p>
  Finding the second a tag, colouring it in red, then display a pop-up on click when clicking Site 2
</p>


<div class="sites">
  <a id="site1" href="https://www.site1.com">Site 1</a>
  <br>
  <a id="site2" href="https://www.site2.com">Site 2</a>
</div>
```

Comment: The IDs aren't making any difference here - the fix here is that `.dialog` is only being called on the click, not on doc.ready. There's no need to add an ID.